# How to find files with .txt extension and put them into a cake php form select input element by using the array_combine function?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm wondering how to find all files within a directory that contain the .txt extension and then create an array_combine with the results.

Comment: First thing, I did not downvoted you. Second point. You should not edit the whole question by deleting all the old statements you wrote. Make a label `Upated:` and then your editing needs to be required. This is just a suggestion for you in future. :)

Comment: You should better ask one question at a time. If you already know that you need to use `array_combine` for the cake php speicfic form element part, remove that and instead only ask for how to retrieve a directory listing of files by the file-extension. That will also allow you to spot the answer quickly by using the search and other features of this site to find related questions / answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the text of the dropdown option, then you should make your array indexes as same as the associative values:

```
$files = glob($dir."/*.[tT][xX][tT]");
$correctFiles = array_combine($files,$files);
Choose text file: <?php echo $this->Form->select('textDrop', array('options' => $correctFiles, 'style' => 'width: 150px;', 'id' => 'textDrop')); ?>
```

Comment: Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: See this doesn't because my array is getting populated through a foreach loop that iterates through a folder and takes out files where their extension is .txt so i can't predfine the $files, $files.

Comment: If you really want to find files based on extension, then you should use glob() instead of scandir(). And the above solution will work exactly what you needed. Actually this point was not mentioned in your question. Otherwise I gave you the answer using glob() php function. Edit your question and I'll give you my edited answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Author asks for lowercase .txt extension if I read the question, actually, literally it's `.txt` not `.tXt` and stuff. And glob also returns directories which pathname matches the pattern. That is not what the author has asked for so. You should better look for duplicates IMHO as those have better answers.

Comment: @hakra. Thanks for downvoting. :) That's why I commented on the main question. The user asked something else before the question was edited. And I just gave him the way of usage of glob() method. Are you realized that I specified extensions, so why it will find directories? See my second comment on my answer. It shows you that user was asked something else. Anyways Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: It finds pathnames: Files, Links and Directories - http://php.net/glob - and before the edit it was even more clear that user is just looking for a file-listing based on extension which is a perfect duplicate question. Better guide the user to the duplicate question via a comment than answering it (again). If you feel there is room for improvement, improve an existing answer instead. Glob is a powerful tool btw, nothing wrong with it per-se. But for more specific things there is [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/iterator_to_array) and [SPL](http://se.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php).